# JWT Strategy always returns Unauthorized

Tags: node.js, passport.js, jwt

I have been trying to adding authorization to my app using JWT and passport. the local strategy seems to be working without any issues but the JWT strategy doesn't seem to be working.

My **Passport.js** file

```
import passport from 'passport';
import User from '../models/regusers.model';
import config from '../config';
import jwtstrategy from 'passport-jwt';
import extractjwt from 'passport-jwt';
import LocalStrategy from 'passport-local';

const JwtStrategy = jwtstrategy.Strategy;
const ExtractJwt = extractjwt.ExtractJwt;

const localOption = {usernameField:'email'};

// create local Strategy
const localLogin = new LocalStrategy(localOption,(email,password,done)=>{
    //verify this username and password, call done true if true or false
    User.findOne({email:email},(err,user)=>{
       if(err){ return done(err);}
       if(!user){ return done(null,false);}

       // compare Password - is 'password' equal to user.password
       user.comparePassword(password,function(err,isMatch){
          if(err){ return done(err); }
          if(!isMatch) { return done(null,false); }

          return done(null,user);
       });
    });
});

// setup options for JWT Strategy
const jwtOptions = {
  jwtFromRequest:ExtractJwt.fromHeader('Authorization'),
  secretOrKey:config.secret
};

// Create JWT Strategy
const jwtLogin = new JwtStrategy(jwtOptions,function(payload,done){
   // see if user id in payload exists in our db
   //if it does, call done with that other
   //otherwise, call done without a user obejct
   User.findById(payload.sub,(err,user)=>{
      if(err){ return done(err,false); }

      if(user){
        done(null,user);
      }else{
        done(null,false);
      }

   });
});

passport.use(jwtLogin);
passport.use(localLogin);
```

My **authentication.js** file

```
import User from '../models/regusers.model';
import jwt from 'jwt-simple';
import config from '../config';
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt-nodejs';

let tokenForUser = (user) =>{
    const timpestamp = new Date().getTime();
    return jwt.encode({sub:user.id,iat:timpestamp},config.secret);
}


let login = (req,res,next) => {
      //User has already had their email and password auth'd
      //We just need to give them a token
      res.send({token:tokenForUser(req.user),unu:req.user.uname});
}

let signup = (req,res,next) => {

    const fname = req.body.fname;
    const lname = req.body.lname;
    const uname = req.body.uname;
    const email = req.body.email;
    const password =req.body.password;

    if(!email || !password){
       return res.status(422).send({error:'You must provide email and password'});
    }

    // See if a user with the given email exists
    User.findOne({email: email },(err,user)=>{
        if(err){
          return next(err);
        }
        //If a user with email does exists, return an erorr
        if(user){
          return res.status(422).send({error:'Email is in use'});
        }
        //if user with email does not exists,create and save user
        const newuser = new User({
          fname:fname,
          lname:lname,
          uname:uname,
          email:email,
          password:password
        });


        newuser.save((err)=>{
            if(err){ return next(err);}
            res.json({token:tokenForUser(newuser)});
            // res.json({success:'true'});
        });


    });
}

module.exports.signup = signup;
module.exports.login = login;
```

the routes where i have used the the authentication middleware

```
import Authentication from '../auth/auth';
import passportService from '../services/passport';
import passport from 'passport';


const requireAuth = passport.authenticate('jwt',{session:false});
const requireLogin = passport.authenticate('local',{session:false});

const user = (app) => {

    app.get('/user',requireAuth,function (req,res){
        res.json({hi:'there'});
    });

    app.post('/login',requireLogin,Authentication.login);

    app.post('/signup',Authentication.signup);
}

export default user;
```

Any reason why im getting the it as Unauthorized when ever i make a get request to the user route.

Comment: Try changing this:

    passport.use(jwtLogin);
    passport.use(localLogin);

To this:

    passport.use('jwt', jwtLogin);
    passport.use('local', localLogin);

Comment: @TRomesh I am also getting the same issue, has your issue gets fixed?

Comment: @AdityaJain Nope i couldn't resolve this issue

Comment: @TRomesh have you narrowed down your program till where it is working, can you tell me the specific line after which you are not getting the response?